# How can I remove a widget in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to do the same as I did to add these widgets, but without success.
I am working with the kv language and bind function. With this code below is possible add a buttons dynamically, but isn't possible remove them.

.py

```
class PrimeiroScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'um'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def fc2(self):
        btn = Button(text="Botão",size_hint=(.1,.1))
        self.ids.grade2.add_widget(btn)     
        btn.bind(on_press=self.printa)

    def printa(self,*args):
        #btn2 = Button(text="Btn2",size_hint=(.1,.1))#I can add another btn succesfully
        self.ids.grade2.add_widget(btn2)#but I can do the same by this way
        self.remove_widget(btn)
        grade2.remove_widget(self.btn)
```

and the .kv

```
<RootScreen>:
    PrimeiroScreen:

<PrimeiroScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: (.5,1)
        id: grade
        Button:
            text: "hi!"
            on_press: root.fc2()

    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'bt-rl'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint: (.5,1)
            id: grade2
```

Has anybody any idea of the mistake I made? Python shows me the message below:

```
self.remove_widget(btn)
NameError: global name 'btn' is not defined
```

Comment: `widget_to_remove.parent.remove_widget(widget_to_remove)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change
`btn = Button(text="Botão",size_hint=(.1,.1))`
to
`self.btn = Button(text="Botão",size_hint=(.1,.1))`
So you make it a class attribute.

And then remove it like this
`self.remove_widget(self.btn)`

Comment: I wrote here that it didn't fine, but I remake my code and I saw I didn't call all "btn = self.btn". This way, I did "self.btn.bind(on_press=self.fc)" and "self.ids.grade2.add_widget(self.btn)". Very thanks, and I am sorry for my neglect. It worked fine.

Comment: To avoid to create another post. How I have to do if I want to add or remove a widget in other class? I am trying the same way as a normal function, because I got it, in a function as change text label. Is it in the same way?

Comment: @victorcd To avoid making answers that does not fit the question. you eiter update the question with an example of what you want, or make a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the widgets inside an element. You can also use

`self.clear_widgets()`

OR

`self.<reference_to_element>.clear_widgets()`